# How to go back to my activity from Browser without losing data?

Tags: android, google-maps, browser

I have created a static ArrayList  where I store data which is parsed from a XML from a server.In that data it contains latitude and longitude also.By using latitude and longitude I open browser to show a route on map.

for this I use

```
String new_url = "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + ServerData.LATITUDE + "," + ServerData.LONGITUDE + "&daddr=" + latitude + "," + longitude ;//+ "&dirroute=r";
Intent intent_map = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(new_url));
startActivity(intent_map);
```

it works fine first it asks me to choose either Browser or Google Map.
I choose Browser then it shows a direction page and on that page I click on route tab so it shows route between two points.

But problem occurs when I come back to my activity page by pressing Back button on keyboard.My all static data is lost and app start showing error.

One more thing I want is can I directly go to route page in browser rather than first going to direction page and then by pressing route tab to go to Route page.

Please Help

Comment: Have you implemented the onResume method?

Comment: Check this [intents list](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html) to view map.

Comment: @ingsaurabh No I haven't.I think I have used static data (for static data I have created a class which contains all the static data which can be used by any Activity within my app) so I can use it from anywhere.